# How to cancel a c2dm register/unregister request

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I'm building an android application that uses the c2dm framework.

To the point: **I want to add some functionality to my application, that would cancel the registration request if that takes more than a few seconds. Preferably using the c2dm framework itself; otherwise some Handler+Runnable.**

I cannot yet see if the framework itself offers such a thing like setting a timeout that the service (<= android's c2dm service) would use to cancel the registration and broadcast an Intent.

I thought about options like ignoring any **com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION**
sent after that grace period but this sounds ridiculous.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cancel request you sent few second ago. ) 
You can don't catch google response after some period. You can get but not save registration_id after some period of time for example

Comment: I'm afraid that this is correct ^^^. I'll wait for one more day in case someone has an idea and then accept your answer. Thx.